# Are the names of guilds in Ravnica protected intellectual property?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, copyright

I don't see a TM symbol anywhere and some searches of the interwebs reveals nothing but laughing cats...

I'm not wanting to infringe, just not step on toes.

(Very big, powerful toes)

Comment: It's worth noting that WotC will only contact you if you are attempting to profit off of them. Personal use, such as making a work of art that uses the names or using them in a fan fiction, are perfectly allowed (as long as you do not sell that art or work of fiction.)

Comment: The question title and the tag says "copyright", but the question body asks about "TM", which stands for "trademark", not copyright.

Comment: For what purpose would you be using the names? This might be an XY problem, where you want to ensure you won't infringe for some purpose, but you're asking about trademark/copyright to determine that — that wouldn't always be an issue but in this case trademark or copyright are only a subsection of intellectual property law that might apply.

Comment: If you have more questions about trademark law, then the best site to ask on is usually https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you, @Acccumulation I did have that mixed up. Intent is to make colorful shirts of guild colors, which is probably OK if I don't have a guild name on it.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars Note that even without a name on them, you wouldn't be allowed to sell them as "Azorius Shirts". If you want something like "Rakdos-inspired shirt", you might need to talk to a lawyer first, because at that point you're getting into complicated legal territory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does seem that wizards has trademarked all of the guild names ([list here](https://trademarks.justia.com/owners/wizards-of-the-coast-llc-2501355)), so I would avoid using them without express permission or a licensing agreement, as wizards could pursue legal action.

However, trademark is primarily for commercial endeavours, so if this is for personal use there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I would add that even personal use - if in a disparaging manner - might be grounds for a law suit if Wizards wanted to enforce a Cease and Desist order.

Comment: They also seem to have trademarked the very word Magic, which seems entirely unenforceable.

Comment: @WeckarE. maybe not - I'm not an expert, but I'm pretty sure that trademarks are use-specific.  So a trademark on Magic means that they could sue other card games named Magic, but not books or movies or magic shows or anything else.  And that's a scope that is narrow enough to be enforceable.

Comment: @WeckarE. a trademark is only applicable for a certain context. I imagine theirs is something like "board games". This protects them from somebody releasing a cheap knock off and calling it "Magic: the Collection". However, if you are, say, a loan shark and call your business "Magic: the Gathering" that should be fine as you are not in the business of board games.

Comment: @Weckar E., Other enforceable trademarks: Windows, Apple, Amazon, Monster, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually, the size of the brand influences whether or not the protection extends beyond the context. For example, Coca Cola is big enough that people might think that the Coca Cola Collectors loan shark is somehow related to the beverage manufacturer. I don't know if MtG is a strong enough brand to be protected like that (my guess is that it would be) but it's definitely not as simple as you set it out to be. (Broadness of the trademarked term is similarly of influence, which is why MtG trademarked Magic: the Gathering instead of just "Magic".)